# C# Timer-Filter for Command

Tags: c#, timer, bots, discord, discord.net

First of all, I am pretty new to coding. I am currently trying to program my Discord-bot and I ran into this issue:

I want to create a command with a timer on it, so everytime someone uses this command, the timer starts ticking and after the timer reached a certain amount of seconds, the user is able to use this command again. The command is a "joke-command" where everytime you use it, the bot tells you a joke.

Is there a way to implement this?

I currently have this:

```
        //joke-integer
        int jokeNumber;
        jokeNumber = 0;

        //joke-list
        joke = new string[]
        {
            "aaa",
            "bbb",
            "ccc",
        };

        //joke-command
        commands.CreateCommand("joke")
            .Do(async e =>
            {

                jokeNumber = jokeNumber + 1;

                if (jokeNumber.Equals(3))
                {
                    jokeNumber = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    jokeNumber = jokeNumber + 0;
                }

                string jokePost = joke[jokeNumber];
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(jokePost);
            });
```

So this (^) just tells you a joke out of a list if you use the command "!joke" but I want that this command is only "enabled" if the timer passed for example 100 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the last time an user has requested the command, and then check this date every time a new command is requested.

Inside your class:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, DateTimeOffset> UsersJokesLastCall = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, DateTimeOffset>();
```

When creating your command:

```
commands.CreateCommand("joke")
    .Do(async e =>
    {
        var id = e.ChannelId; // example using channel id as unique key

        var nowUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        var canReturnJoke = true;
        UsersJokesLastCall.AddOrUpdate(id, nowUtc, (key, oldValue) =>
        {
            var elapsed = nowUtc - oldValue; // check elapsed time
            if(elapsed.TotalSeconds < 100)
            {
                canReturnJoke = false; // min time has not passed
                return oldValue; // do not change the last joke time
            }
            return nowUtc; // update to current time
        });

        if(!canReturnJoke)
        {
            // return something to the user
            await e.Channel.SendMessage("Try later");
            return;
        }

        jokeNumber = jokeNumber + 1;

        if (jokeNumber.Equals(3))
        {
            jokeNumber = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            jokeNumber = jokeNumber + 0;
        }

        string jokePost = joke[jokeNumber];
        await e.Channel.SendMessage(jokePost);
    });
```

You may need to further work on this code, but this should give you the overall approach.

Comment: It says that "nowUtc" doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: I did forget to add `var nowUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;`. Fixed now.

Comment: Now in the line `UsersJokesLastCall.AddOrUpdate(id, nowUtc, (key, oldValue) =>` it's saying on "id" "cannot convert from 'ulong' to 'string' and on "nowUtc" it's saying "cannot convert from 'System.DateTimeOffset' to 'Sytem.Func<string, System.DateTimeOffset>' "

Comment: As I said, you have to work on the code. If the id is long and not string then use long as key type for the ConcurrentDictionary